# Having troubles with reading strings from a file into an array, to ultimately sort

Tags: c, arrays, file, quicksort

I have a project that I'm finishing up where I have to read in strings from a text file and do a quick sort on them. I feel like I have my quick sort function down, but seem to be having problems with my code not going past reading the strings and storing them in the array in my while loop. I put a simple print statement to see if it was reading them and it seems to be doing so as it prints all of the strings out. However, after outputting the strings, it exits on a segmentation fault and won't continue to sort the strings out. I was looking for some advice on what I may be missing or not doing correctly. I'll just post the code where I'm reading the file to store the strings in my array since that's where the error begins.

There are 64 strings total in the file, but I'll post a few and not all.

```
Strings from text file

lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
etiam
et
magna
ut
sem
gravida
efficitur
pellentesque
magna
elit
posuere
sit
amet
```

Actual code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define WORDSNUM 128

void print_list(char * array2[], int size2);
void swapping_words(char * my_array[], int a, int b);
void quicksort_list(char * word[], int begin, int end);
int partition(char * array5[], int e, int f);

int main() {

    FILE * fp;  
    fp = fopen("Project08Data.txt", "r");

    char * text_words[WORDSNUM];

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error, no file provided or not read properly.\n");
    }

    while(fgets(text_words, WORDSNUM, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", text_words); //print statement I was using to see if the strings were being read in at least
    }

    fclose(fp);
    //These are the functions for my quick sort and printing the list after
    quicksort_list(text_words, 0, WORDSNUM - 1);
    print_list(text_words, WORDSNUM);
}
```

Comment: A good starting point would be to eliminate the compile-time errors you're getting.  `fgets` requires a `char *` for its first argument, not a `char **`.  You will also need to allocate space for each of the pointers in `text_words`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of pointers to characters with `char * text_words[WORDSNUM];` but you are not allocating any memory for those pointers. Actually, we don't even know where they point to because they were not initialized. So you're writing to unallocated and unspecified areas of the memory, resulting in the segmentation fault.

You could use `malloc` to allocate space in the memory where you'll write the words to.